# Find XPath of element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

How do I find the XPath for the hamburger navigation icon (3 white lines) at https://freerice.com/game in the upper left corner? I am writing a Python program with selenium and would like it to click this button.

I've used it so far:

```
b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Path_7605"]')
b.click
```

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: What button in the upper right corner? The Login button?

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code should do it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/header/div[2]/a/span").click()
```

You can just use `find_element_by_xpath` and paste in the xpath of whatever element you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='toolbar__menu-toggle-icon']").click();
```